# Crystal Runtime DLLs missing

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have been fighting this for a few days.  I couldn't add Crystal Report Viewers to Visual Studio.  The Viewer was in the toolbox but it would not display on the form.  It only appeared at the bottom where the timers and other non-visual objects would appear.

I have completely uninstalled the Crystal runtime and reinstalled from scratch.  I am on version 13.0.24.  Control panel tells me I have both runtimes installed successfully.  I ran CRVS2010CR3224_0-10010309 and CRVS2010CR6424_0-10010309.

I go to look for the CrystalDecisions DLLs and they are nowhere to be found.  They aren't in C:\Windows\Assemblies\ they aren't in C:\Windows\Microsft.Net\Assemblies\ and they aren't in SAP's Program files directory.  I have no idea where they are.

I tried operating off of 13.0.35 from nuget but I kept getting an error when declaring a new Report document saying "Document was not opened" so I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have an error or other unknown problems when installing the Crystal Report runtime. You can check in the following link for learning how to [install Crystal Report Runtime
and how to Create Crystal Report](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/).